HttpClientTestingModule is deprecated, how to replace it?
After upgrading my application to Angular 18.0.4, my test classes say:
'HttpClientTestingModule' is deprecated. Add provideHttpClientTesting() to your providers instead.
Therefore I adapted my code as follows:
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule(
            {
                imports: [
                    AssetDetailsComponent,
                ],
                providers: [
                    // replacement for HttpClientTestingModule:
                    provideHttpClientTesting() 
                ]
            })
            .compileComponents();

However, when I run the tests, I get the following error:
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[AssetDetailsComponent])[InventoryActionService -> InventoryActionService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
      NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!

If I use provideHttpClient() instead of provideHttpClientTesting() it works, yet I doubt that this is best practice. What is the correct solution to this issue?

Also add provideHttpClient() before provideHttpClientTesting()
providers: [
   provideHttpClient(),
   provideHttpClientTesting() 
]

As mentioned in the docs.

Thanks for your quick answer: Can this information be found in the official Angular documentation? I searched for it, but had no luck..

I've added the doc to my answer.

You need provideHttpClient() alsom Since provideHttpClientTesting() configures env but does not provide httpClient, Include provideHttpClient() like below:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AssetDetailsComponent } from './asset-details.component';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideHttpClientTesting } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
   

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    AssetDetailsComponent,
  ],
  providers: [        
    provideHttpClient(), // Provide the HttpClient along with HttpClientTesting
    provideHttpClientTesting(),
  ]
}).compileComponents();

